# Constant Plugin URL

Tags: wordpress

I just installed the RTA Plugin for a website and it has given me an error message :

```
constant plugins_url - assumed 'plugins_url' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/scudhub1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/restricted-to-adults/compat.php on line 13
```

I will be honest, I'm no programmer nor code writer, and I've tried look on the net to see if anyone else has had the same ^problem without any luck, so I'm hoping someone could throw some light onto the subject to help me out.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not the place to get help with WordPress Plugins. Please contact the developer of the plugin or use the specific support board for that plugin to find a solution to your problem. Besides that: Looks like a warning for a deprecated feature. It's not critical. Yet. You should really contact the developer though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know.. I did contact the developer but with no success in getting a reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at that line of code [here](https://github.com/WPPlugins/restricted-to-adults/blob/master/compat.php#L13) you can see where the code is giving a warning.

You can change it to the following by updating `compat.php` file:

```
if ( !function_exists('plugins_url') ) {
```